# Bubble Sort in C#

Tags: algorithm, sorting, c#-4.0, bubble-sort

I am studying algorithms and I have two bubble sort functions/methods and both of them provide similar result.  Can please someone tell me something more about them, such as performance etc?

```
public void BubbleSort() {
        int temp;
        for (int outer = upper; outer >= 1; outer--) {
            for (int inner = 0; inner <= outer - 1; inner++) {
                if ((int)arr[inner] > arr[inner + 1]) {
                    temp = arr[inner];
                    arr[inner] = arr[inner + 1]; 
                    arr[inner + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

public void BubbleSor2() {
    int temp;
    for (int outer = 0; outer < upper - 1; outer++) {
        for (int inner = 1; inner <= upper; inner++) {
           if ((int)arr[outer] > arr[inner]) {
               temp = arr[inner];
               arr[inner] = arr[outer];
               arr[outer] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this version of Bubble Sort.

```
public void BubbleSort()
{
    int temp;
    for (int outer = 0; outer < upper - 1; outer++)
    {
        for (int inner = 0; inner < upper - outer; inner++)
        {
            if (arr[inner + 1] < arr[inner])
            {
                temp = arr[inner + 1];
                arr[inner + 1] = arr[inner];
                arr[inner] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

They are reverse of each-other, however, the implementation is incorrect. Replace it with this one:

```
public void BubbleSort() {
        int temp;
        for (int outer = upper; outer >= 1; outer--) {
            for (int inner = outer - 1; inner >= 0; inner--) {
                if (arr[inner] < arr[outer]) {
                    temp = arr[inner];
                    arr[inner] = arr[outer]; 
                    arr[outer] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }

public void BubbleSor2() {
    int temp;
    for (int outer = 0; outer < upper - 1; outer++) {
        for (int inner = outer + 1; inner < upper; inner++) {
           if (arr[inner] > arr[outer]) {
               temp = arr[inner];
               arr[inner] = arr[outer];
               arr[outer] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The complexity of both is quadratic (O(n^2))

Answer (score 0):

The first one have a n loop outside. Here n  = upper - 1; And inside in every iteration it runs one less than the previous iteration. So it runs `(n*(n-1))/2 = (n^2-n)/2` times. Which is O(n^2)complexity.

The second one is not a bubble sort although it's result will be the same as the first one. And it runs in O(n^2) complexity.

The first one in the first iteration puts the maximum value in `arr` in the `upper`th position. In the second iteration puts the second maximum value in `arr` in `upper-1` th postion and the third iteration put the third maximum in the `upper-2`th position and so on. Each time the maximum value is put in the `(last position of array - iteration number)`th postion. Hence the bubble sort.

The second one does the same goal but with different apporach. In the first iteration puts the minimum value in `arr` in the `0`th position. In the second iteration puts the second minimum value in `arr` in `1` th postion and the third iteration put the third maximum in the `2`nd position and so on. Each time the minimum value is put in the `iteration number-1`th postion.