# What does System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.' mean? - How to Bubble Sort in C#?

Tags: c#, loops, sorting, iteration, bubble-sort

I'm doing a programming task for my course and I've been challenged to do it in C#. When I run it, it highlights **numbers[position+1]** and gives me the error: **System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            // array of numbers
            int[] numbers = { 9, 5, 4, 15, 3, 8, 11, 2 };

            int noOfNumbers = 8;

            int temp;

            while (noOfNumbers > 1) {

                foreach(int position in numbers) {

                    if (numbers[position] > numbers[position+1])
                    {

                        temp = numbers[position];

                        numbers[position] = numbers[position + 1];

                        numbers[position + 1] = temp;

                    }

                }
                noOfNumbers = noOfNumbers + 1;

            }

            Console.WriteLine(numbers);


        }
    }
}
```

Here is the pseudocode:

```
BEGIN
Numbers=[9,5,4,15,3,8,11,2]
AmountOfNumbers=8
Temp=0
WHILE AmountOfNumbers>1
    FOR each itemPositionInArray in Numbers
        IF Numbers[ItemPositionInArray] > Numbers[ItemPositionInArray+1]
            Temp=Numbers[ItemPositionInArray]
            Numbers[ItemPositionInArray]=Numbers[ItemPositionInArray+1]
            Numbers[ItemPositionInArry+1]=Temp
    AmountOfNumbers=AmountOfNumbers-1
OUTPUT(Numbers)
END
```

Comment: `foreach(int position in numbers) {`  This doesn't loop over their *positions*, it loops over the numbers *themselves*.  The value `position` takes on the first iteration of the loop will be 9, not 0.

Comment: The duplicate explains what that error means. Then if you start to use the debugger you will see that the first _position_ is equal to 9 and this, of course, is _out of range_ when you use it as it was an index into the numbers array

Comment: Change `foreach(int position in numbers)` to `for (int position = 0; position < numbers.Length; position++)`

Comment: For a bubblesort, you should use a boolean to check if something is changed. Inside the `if (numbers[position] > numbers[position+1])`, if nothing is swapped, you're ready

Comment: @RandRandom that will crash as well

Comment: @Steve - yeah, but I thought `position+1` would make more sense for OP that way

Comment: Also there is another big problem here. The while loop is an infinite loop.

Comment: @Steve - maybe reopen to help OP to fix all the problems, and not only the problem at hand?

Comment: @RandRandom OP didn't ask about other problems. OP asked about index out of range exceptions, which is a duplicate. If OP has other problems they want resolved, they should ask a separate question.

Comment: @TylerH - not quite right, OP has `How to Bubble sort in C#?` in this question title.

Comment: Sure, but that's also a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23310345/bubble-sort-in-c-sharp), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1595244/whats-the-most-elegant-way-to-bubble-sort-in-c), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14768010/simple-bubble-sort-c-sharp), and I'm sure many more.

Answer (score 4):

The problem in your code is here: *(like Amy said)*

```
foreach(int position in numbers) {
    if (numbers[position] > numbers[position+1])
```

You're using the position as index to the array. The foreach will enumerate your array and will put in the element values into the `position` variable, not the index. So the first iteration position will contain 9 (not index 0)

For this you should use the "normal" for-loop.

```
for(int i=0; i < count; i++) { }
```

---

Here's an example to do a bubblesort. I've written some comment to explain what it does.

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // array of numbers
        int[] numbers = { 9, 5, 4, 15, 3, 8, 11, 2 };

        // declare a boolean.
        bool done;

        do
        {
            // when nothing happens, you're done.
            done = true;

            // create a for-loop to iterate all item-1 (except the last)
            for(int position=0;position<numbers.Length-1;position++)
            {
                // compare the values in the array
                if (numbers[position] > numbers[position+1])
                {
                    // swap the values
                    int temp = numbers[position];

                    numbers[position] = numbers[position + 1];

                    numbers[position + 1] = temp;

                    // if something was swapped, you're not ready.
                    done = false;
                }
            }

            // loop until done is set.
        } while (!done);

        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", numbers));
    }
}
```

[Here's an .NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lUX9Ev)